# How to return public URL to download file?

Tags: laravel

I store file to local server using this:

```
  Storage::put("public/pdf/conclusions/{$pdfname}", $pdf->output(), 'public');
```

How to return a URL link to download file from client side?

I tried this:

```
 return asset($pdfname);
```

I get this link:

```
https://huina/public/pdf/conclusions/18022022_54_conclusions.pdf
```

When I try to open file by this link I get route error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `php artisan storage:link`. It'll create a symbolic link from `/public` to `/storage/app/public`